# How to remove an element from a many2many field?

Tags: odoo-8, odoo

I'm trying to remove a group element from the `many2many` list in the model `res.groups`. In particular I'm trying to remove the "Analytic Accounting" group from the Employee (`implied_ids` field):

```xml
<record model="res.groups" id="base.group_user">
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(3, ref('analytic.group_analytic_accounting'))]"/>
</record>
```

I use the number three because I read it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26011102/openerp-odoo-model-relationship-xml-syntax):

```
(3, ID) => cut the link to the linked record with id = ID 
           (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)
```

But the element doesn't dissapear from the list. Do I need to do anything else? Am I doing it in a wrong way?

Comment: This looks good. But I don't think `group_analytic_accounting` is by default in `group_user`'s `implied_ids`... Why would it be on your system?