# How to insert data into account_move and account_move_line tables in a single PostgreSQL Query?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-9

I want to ask about a query.
So I want to create a single query that can insert data into 2 tables. What I want to do is, first of all I need to create a data in account_move table,and then from that created account_move there's an ID. 
And then I want to use the ID that was created from account_move table to be used as a move_id in account_move_line table to create data on it.

How do I do that in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

**Insert records with ORM method**

I recommend you to create the records on account_move with the orm method `create`. The One2many field which point to the `account.move.line` on the `account.move` model is `line_id`, so:

```py
line1 = {
    'name': line1_name,
    'account_id': line1_account_id,

    # [...]
}

line2 = {
    'name': line2_name,
    'account_id': line2_account_id,

    # [...]
}

move = {
    'journal_id': journal_id,
    'period_id': period_id,
    'date': move_date,
    'line_id': [
        (0, 0,  { line1 }),
        (0, 0,  { line2 })
    ],

    # [...]
}

self.env['account.move'].create(move)
```

You must add each record with `(0, 0,  { line1 })`, you could check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26011102/openerp-odoo-model-relationship-xml-syntax) for more information

About [orm methods](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#common-orm-methods)

**Insert records with PostgreSQL**

If you still want to run a postgresql query you can use the [WITH statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

> You can use data-modifying statements (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE) in
>   WITH. This allows you to perform several different operations in the
>   same query. An example is

```sql
WITH moved_rows AS (
    DELETE FROM products
    WHERE
        "date" >= '2010-10-01' AND
        "date" < '2010-11-01'
    RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO products_log
SELECT * FROM moved_rows;
```